# Python: Understanding reduce()'s 'initializer' argument

Tags: python, functional-programming, reduce, fold, higher-order-functions

I'm relatively new to Python and am having trouble
with **Folds** or more specifically, `reduce()`'s  'initializer' argument

e.g. `reduce(function, iterable[, initializer])`

**Here is the function...**

```
>>> def x100y(x,y):
...     return x*100+y
```

**Could someone explain why reduce() produces 44...**

```
>>> reduce(x100y, (), 44)
44
```

**or why it produces 30102 here...**

```
>>> reduce(x100y, [1,2], 3)
30102
```

Comment: Same question as @TimPeters. Also, have you read [this](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce)? In particular, the code shown after "Roughly equivalent to:"? Follow that code line by line with your parameter values and that ought to explain the behavior you are observing.

Comment: Google search says `x100y` is from http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/python/web/reduce-function.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the docs:

> #### [reduce(function, iterable[, initializer])](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce)
>
> Apply function of two
>     arguments cumulatively to the items of iterable, from left to right,
>     so as to reduce the iterable to a single value. For example,
>     `reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])` calculates
>     `((((1+2)+3)+4)+5)`. The left argument, x, is the accumulated value and
>     the right argument, y, is the update value from the iterable. If the
>     optional initializer is present, it is placed before the items of the
>     iterable in the calculation, and serves as a default when the iterable
>     is empty. If initializer is not given and iterable contains only one
>     item, the first item is returned.

The initializer is placed as element 0 in your iterable and if there are no elements in your iterable it is returned. (So this is why you get 44)

Also, x100y is not a valid python function. If you want to make it into a valid python function you would have to do

```
reduce(lambda x,y: x*100*y,[1,2],3)
```

which is equivalent to

(3*100*1)*100*2 which should give 60000 (why you got the value you had is probably because of an error)

Documentation on lambda is [here](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#lambda)

Comment: Thank you sir. I read the docs but how you put it is much more clear. Again, just so I'm clear: If one argument is provided **(e.g.reduce(x100y, [15]) or reduce(x100y, (), 44))**, reduce() won't run and instead returns the number provide?

Comment: @KevinZerbo Read again: the initializer will influence  the calculation in any case. It is no more nor less than the starting value for the accumulator.

Comment: @KevinZerbo you are right. So basically the reduce(x100y,[15]) is equivalent to reduce(x100y,[], 15). Since there aren't enough elements in the iterable to complete the function x100y it simply returns 15 instead of running it through the function.